# C# File Monitoring

Tags: c#, timer, monitoring

This applies to a previous question I had asked.  I have been trying to create an application that will allow me to monitor a file and alert me if the file has stopped changing.  Someone recommended just checking the file size and using a timer in a Windows service.  I have taken their advice but I am not very good with Windows Services.  I am trying to do the file comparison between two files that I have created.  Below is the code

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Test.txt";
    string logPath = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Log.txt";
    string newLog = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Log1.txt";


    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = 60000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.AutoReset = true;
        timer1.Start();

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
        long s1 = f.Length;

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(logPath))
        {
            file.WriteLine(s1.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
        long s2 = f.Length;

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newLog))
        {
            file.WriteLine(s2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What I can not figure out is how to reference s1 in the timer_elapsed method.  I tried declaring it globally but it would not work.  I want to just be able to do something like this in the timer elapsed method.

```
        if (s1 == s2)
        {
            //send email
        }

        else
        {
            //don't do anything
        }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you meant you tried declaring it as a field in the class?  What exactly `did not work` when you tried that?

Comment: Correct.  The error was "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property."

Comment: What is your logic for determining when a file has stopped growing versus the file growth momentarily paused?

Comment: @JohnFx I have read your comment 5 times and I still cannot figure out what you mean.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question... but instead of checking the file size on a timer. I would use the FileSystemWatcher in .NET. Then set a timer (how long you're willing to wait to be sure the file has stopped changing). In the FileSystemWatcher.Changed event handler, reset your timer. If the timer ever elapses... you know the the file hasn't changed in that length of time.

Comment: The only reason I suggest this approach instead is if the file does change... but the file size doesn't (example: a single character is changed) then your current solution will not work.

Comment: If there is not a whole line (100 characters) then there is still a problem.  The file is basically a log that stores transactions.

Comment: @Matt - sorry. What I meant was: How do you know when a file has stopped changing. Do you have a timeout in mind or something?

Comment: Yes my timer would run every few minutes and constantly check the file size of the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do it like this:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Test.txt";
    string logPath = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Log.txt";
    string newLog = @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\New folder\Log1.txt";
    long oldFileSize; // Add this line

    public void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = 60000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.AutoReset = true;
        timer1.Start();

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
        oldFileSize = f.Length; // change this line

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(logPath))
        {
            file.WriteLine(s1.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
        long s2 = f.Length;

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newLog))
        {
            if (s2 == oldFileSize)
            {
                // Send Email
            }
            file.WriteLine(s2.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the FileSystemWatcher class.  There's settings for NotifyFilter / Path / IncludeSubdirectories.

Also, this class raises a bunch of events for Changed, Created, Deleted, Renamed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: How will that help him know when the file STOPS growing?

Comment: choices are either poll (loop with timer) or use an event as a trigger as suggested here.  To me events are just cleaner, and more flexible.    re: when it stops growing, that can be problematic for either approach esp. for something growing over many minutes.  In this case you could set a threshold (say no activity for 10 minutes), or you should request a signal from the feeder process.  e.g. feeder process creates files fileName.ext.started fileName.ext.complete.  Some assumptions made here.  Need to know more about the scenario.

Comment: Thanks sgtz.  I will research that for updates.  Right now, I need something short term until we can get an enterprise wide logging application.  I have tested the service many times over and it is working for what I need it to do.  I agree though that I will probably have issues if I decide to use this long term.